# How to make collisions more OOP style

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a game in pygame. My main problem is how to realize pygame collisions in one class. I have lots of collision detection in my game could I do them less in one class or something like that. There are also some group collisions.

Also does lots of collisions effects optimization of games(Not that game I'm talking about 3A games).

```py
    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.score += self.start_time
        collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
        collideGroup = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullet_list, self.enemyRocket, True, True)
        collideGroupPlat = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullet_list, self.platforms, True, False)
        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.enemyRocket, False)
        collideWithEND = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.endLevel, False)
        collideWithFuel = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullet_list, self.fuel, True, True)

        if collision:
            self.player_health -= 1
            self.new()
        if collide:
            self.player_health -= 1
            self.new()
        if collideGroup:
            self.score += 10
        if collideWithEND:
            self.level += 1
        if collideWithFuel:
            self.fuelBar += 10
```

Should I add in sprites classes some functions to detect collisions or should I open another class for collisions.
Here are my spites classes.

```py
    class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, pos_x, pos_y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images', img)).convert()
        self.image.convert_alpha()
        self.image.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (pos_x, pos_y)
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.vy = -5
            if self.rect.y < 0:
                self.rect.y += 5
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.vy = 3
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.vx = 3
            if self.rect.x > (WIDTH-58):
                self.rect.x -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.vx = -5
            if self.rect.x < 0:
                self.rect.x += 5

        self.rect.x += self.vx
        self.rect.y += self.vy


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((5, 3))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.vx = 0

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.rect.x += self.vx
        if self.rect.x > WIDTH:
            self.kill()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.vx = 2
        self.rect.x += self.vx
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible to do that.

Comment: It can be cleaned up with tuples and `dict`s but that doesn't make it better OO. If you show your classes (our player class and enemyRocket class would be the most useful) it would be a lot easier to help you. You class objects should have collision methods which handles their logic.

Comment: Here I added my sprites classes

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one class the `enum` module probably is what you're after: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

If you don't want one class only why not make a baseclass of some sort and all the variants children to that (maybe as singletons - i have code for that if you're interested)